# SAS Proc means: How to capture non default statistics in output dataset such as nmiss p1 p99 etc?

Tags: sas

Original Question:

By default Proc Means outputs N, MIN, MEAN, MAX and STD in the **output dataset**. How do I add, NMISS, P1, P5 etc to this list?

---

Additional info 1:

I want statistics on all numeric variables in my dataset. So I use `_numeric_` in the var specification.

I wan't each statistic to be in a row and variables for columns.

```
 Obs _TYPE_ _FREQ_ _STAT_    var1   var2 var3 etc    
 1     0    84829  N      84826.00
 2     0    84829  MIN        0.00
 3     0    84829  MAX     5000.00
 4     0    84829  MEAN     151.22
 5     0    84829  STD     1989.47
 6     0    84829  NMISS       3
 7     0    84829  P1         2.00
 8     0    84839  P99     4999.00
```

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This paper has an excellent discussion of the exact issue you describe, along with macro code to output a dataset fitting your description.

[A Better Means — The ODS Data Trap](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/059-31.pdf)

Update:
I've discovered that there is a more recent paper that "presents a revised version of the macro supporting additional features and eliminating a surprising error." This is the updated solution:

[Solve the SAS® ODS Data Trap in PROC MEANS](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/231-2012.pdf)

The macro appears well designed and avoids a wide variety of possible issues. The contortions used to create the output dataset involve calls to `proc means` (of course), `proc sql`, `proc contents`, and `proc datasets` and extensive use of the macro language architecture, and a description of them would probably not be instructive in this answer. I don't claim to understand it entirely myself.

However, once you have compiled the macro you should be able to create your desired dataset with one simple statement.

```
%better_means(data=MyDataSet)
```

Now that I've found this convenient solution I may start to use it myself.

Comment: That's a pretty good paper (and one I've found helpful from time to time), but SO doesn't like link-only answers.  It's better to include the important elements of the link here (although in this case I wouldn't include the entire macro).

Comment: @Joe - I attempted to add some more context, but I'm not certain what would make the answer better or more instructive. What would you recommend, to answer more completely in the future?

Comment: Honestly for this specific thing I'm not sure what I'd have done either.  Normally I would include the text of the macro (so that someone googling for this problem and finding this post could just copy it in), but that macro is way too long to include in the answer; and given the result is just 'run this macro', I'm not sure exactly what is best.  What you put in seems good to me.  (Though I don't think the answer actually helps the OP, given his edit, but that's a side note.)

Comment: Thank you very much. The details in the two papers are great! I will try running the macros.

Comment: FYI - I posted this over in [meta] in [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183542/best-way-to-write-a-link-primary-post-linked-to-a-white-paper/183543#183543).  The consensus was that if you want to post a paper like this, also post enough for a user to replicate the approach taken in the paper without reading the paper (not the code necessarily, but the strategy/approach taken).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using the output option in proc means (and not ODS OUTPUT), you can control what comes in that dataset like so:

```
proc means data=sashelp.class;
var age;
class sex;
output out=mymeans nmiss= P1= P5= /autoname;
run;
```

The full list of statistic names is available in the [PROC MEANS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146729.htm) under "statistics keyword".

You can also achieve the same result (with a slightly different output format) with ODS OUTPUT.

```
ods output summary=mymeans;
ods trace on;
proc means data=sashelp.class nmiss p1 p5;
var age;
class sex;
run;
ods trace off;
ods output close;
```

ODS TRACE on/off is to show the name of the table created (ie, 'summary').  It's not needed in production.  In this case you ask for statistics the same way you ask for them to the output window (in the PROC MEANS statement).

Based on your edits, you want it transposed (one row per statistic).  You can't get that directly, but the transposition isn't very hard.

```
proc means data=sashelp.class nmiss p1 p5;
class sex;
var _numeric_;
output out=mymeans n= mean= nmiss= p1= p5= /autoname ;
run;

data mymeans_out;
set mymeans(drop=_type_ _freq_);
by sex;
array numvars _numeric_;
format var stat $32.;
do _t = 1 to dim(numvars);
 var=scan(vname(numvars[_t]),1,'_');
 stat=scan(vname(numvars[_t]),-1,'_');
 value = numvars[_t];
 output;
end;
keep sex var stat value;
run;
```

This has a few limitations.  If your variable names have underscores in them already, the `var=scan...` line will need to be rewritten to use substr and find the last underscore, then `var = substr(vname(...),1,position_of_last_underscore)`.  Stat should be fine since it uses -1 (reverse direction).  If your variable names might exceed ~23 characters, you may not get the exact variable name back out again as it may be truncated or modified.  If that's the case, then the ODS OUTPUT solution from above will help you (as it provides in an additional column the name of the original variable), but some more work would be needed to relate that value to the truncated name.

I also drop `_TYPE_` and `_FREQ_`, to simplify the array definition; if you need those, then you'd need to write a bit of code to exclude them from separately being output, and keep them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have added additional info to my questions.

Comment: Modifed to reflect that additional request.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I really appreciate it. But I needed something more for my dataset which the papers in the other solution offers.